# what does editable mean?

Tags: java, android

what `editable` means in this code?

`private boolean checkPassword(Editable uname, Editable passwd) {`

and why I have to put it there? because when I removed it, it causes an error

heres the full code

```
package course.examples.helloWorldWithLogin;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginScreen extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

    final EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_edittext);
    final EditText passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edittext);
    final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkPassword(uname.getText(), passwd.getText())) {
                Intent helloAndroidIntent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,
                        HelloAndroid.class);
                startActivity(helloAndroidIntent);
            } else {
                uname.setText("");
                passwd.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkPassword(Editable uname, Editable passwd) {
    // Just pretending to extract text and check password
    return new Random().nextBoolean();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), where you can input text. Since the text in the `EditText` can change, android has decided that it should use an object of type `Editable` (among some reasons to enhance speed). From the Editable documentation:

> This is the interface for text whose content and markup can be changed (as opposed to immutable text like Strings).
>
> If you make a DynamicLayout of an Editable, the layout will be reflowed as the text is changed.

Thus, calling `getText()` on an `EditText` returns an `Editable`. To get a string from the Editable, call `myEdittext.getText().toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) is an interface.

> This is the interface for text whose content and markup can be changed
>   (as opposed to immutable text like Strings). If you make a
>   DynamicLayout of an Editable, the layout will be reflowed as the text
>   is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Its the type of the parameter.  Java is a strongly typed language, it needs to know the type of every variable in the program.  In this case, the variable must be of type Editable, or any child type or implementor of Editable.  Since Editable is an interface, it will be an implementor.  If it was a class, it would be an instance of it or a child type of it.